# How to use a custom UITableViewCell with xib without a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` named `CustomTableViewCell` having xib.

The code for the `CustomTableViewCell` is as follows-

```swift
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
}
```

In a `UITableViewController`, I use the `CustomTableViewCell` as follows-

- in `viewDidLoad()`, the `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` is called.
- in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` function, the `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` is called and the text for the `label1` is set.

The code works as expected and the `CustomTableviewCell` is visible when the app is run.

There is another custom `UIViewController` with xib. To this xib file, I would like to add the `CustomTableViewCell` as a subView.

I added a `UIView` to the xib and set it's class to `CustomTableViewCell`. When the app is run, the app crashes because the `label` IBOutlet is nil.

Can anyone point out how to fix this issue?

Comment: Sublcasses of UITableViewCell are made to use on TableViews, you should sublcass UIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are trying to do is achieveable but in a different way. UITableView cells are automatically instantiated by UITableViews only. So by setting the class name won't instantiate the CustomTableViewCell.

The solution is: 
Every UITableView cells are subclass of UIView, so what we can do is instantiate the CustomTableView cell ourself through nib and add the view programmatically in a container view which we can put in the UIViewController.

Here is the code that might help you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: CustomTableViewCell.self), bundle: nil)
     if let customTableViewCell = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? CustomTableViewCell {
        customTableViewCell.label1.text = "Hello"
        containerView.addSubview(customTableViewCell)
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom UIViewcell , you can create uiviewcell using xib and give the particular cell a reusable identifier..then use that particular uiview cell while defining tableviewcell in the uiviewcontroller.